# Searching for users by Total Contributions (CiviContribute, Drupal7)

Tags: drupal, civicontribute, search

I process donations on a third party site and would like to import these records to CiviContribute.

I've imported each donation as a separate contribution, e.g. Peter has made a donation on 14/01/19 for $500.00 and on 15/07/18 for $800.00. This is so I can track how many donations are made on average, whether donation sizes are increasing for donors who make multiple donations, etc.

I'd like to add all donors who have donated over $1000.00 in total, to a smart group so they can receive tailored email content. However when I do searches, it only shows users based on whether they have donated $1000.00 in one individual donation, not by their lifetime donations.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also a "custom search" in CiviCRM called "Contribution Aggregate". This is a very simple search that has been around for a long time but it may be sufficient for your needs.

It can be used by navigating to >>Search >>Custom Searches >>Contribution Aggregate

Answer (score 2):

If I read you right, I would recommend the [Summary Fields](https://github.com/progressivetech/net.ourpowerbase.sumfields) extension which then lets you have a standard Custom Field for Total Contributions and you can build smart groups etc off that field.

(Note (Feb 2019) there has been very recent discussion about some blips with the latest release (https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=summary%20fields)